# bug IE 11 with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

there are a bug on IE 11 when i empty the html in a DIV and I remove class in the list with JavaScriptS. 
The DIV loses the syle CSS "Overflow:auto" and guard is a great height
There is no bug on another navigator.

Sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS</title>  
<style>
div {
 margin: 5px;
}
ul {
 margin: 5px;
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
}
ul li.selected {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.dest {
 width: 500px;
 min-height: 21px;
 max-height: 120px;
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #f9f9f0;
 padding: 3px;
}
.dest span {
 display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 2px;  
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
 line-height: 21px;
 height: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
 window.onload = function(){  
  document.getElementById("btclear").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML = "";
  };
  document.getElementById("btclearplus").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML = "";
   var ul = document.getElementById("list");
   var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].className = "";
   }
  };
  document.getElementById("btall").onclick = function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "first name " + i + " last name " + i;    
    document.getElementById("dest").appendChild(span);
   }
   var ul = document.getElementById("list");
   var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].className = "selected";
   }
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "nom" + i + " prenom" + i;      
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
   }  
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="dest" class="dest"></div>
 <div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>  
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="btall">Select all</button>
  <button id="btclear">Clear all</button>
  <button id="btclearplus">Clear all and deselect</button>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you, Jean-Pierre

Comment: just wtf is the last line? thank you who? and how is he related to this awful question|

Comment: @knitevision, his name is Jean-Pierre. Please mind your language, this ain't any Social Networking site.

Answer (score 0):

change the one of the loops variable `i` to `j` because you have same variable in both loops

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {

         // do you logic
    }       
}
```

Comment: hello, the loops are not cascaded

Comment: @Jp Riton: did you tried by changing variable name ?

Comment: It is a mistake on my part, there is a loop but that does not correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the double loop, the problem was not that here.
In Internet Explorer, you must click the "Select All" button and then the button  "Clear all and deselect" to reproduce the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS</title>  
<style>
div {
 margin: 5px;
}
ul {
 margin: 5px;
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
}
ul li.selected {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.dest {
 width: 500px;
 min-height: 21px;
 max-height: 120px;
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #f9f9f0;
 padding: 3px;
}
.dest span {
 display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 2px;  
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
 line-height: 21px;
 height: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
 window.onload = function(){  
  document.getElementById("btclear").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML = "";
  };
  document.getElementById("btclearplus").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML = "";
   var ul = document.getElementById("list");
   var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].className = "";
   }
  };
  document.getElementById("btall").onclick = function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "first name " + i + " last name " + i;    
    document.getElementById("dest").appendChild(span);
   }
   var ul = document.getElementById("list");
   var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].className = "selected";
   }
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML = "nom" + i + " prenom" + i;      
   document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }  
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="dest" class="dest"></div>
 <div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>  
 </div>
 <div>
  <button id="btall">Select all</button>
  <button id="btclear">Clear all</button>
  <button id="btclearplus">Clear all and deselect</button>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you, Jean-Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Overflow: Auto problem / bug in IE

```
.element { overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible; width: 450px; }
```

[DEMO](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/overflow-auto-problem-bug-in-ie/)